# Vb10 how to copy textbox to webbrowser login page?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to create an application to login into a website .

How to copy text from my textbox into login form in webbrowser

```
<input name="yesID" type="text" class="textbox" style="width:260px;color:grey;">
<input name="password" type="password" maxlength="16" class="textbox" 
       style="width:260px;" onkeypress="return submitenter(this,event)">
<a class="redButtonLG" onclick="javascript:return 
    onSubmit(document.getElementById('loginFormId'), 'doLoginCareConfirmation');">
      <img src="docroot/images/postpaidXpress/btn_login.png">
</a>
```

For example:
txtID.text for ID,
txtPassword.text for Password,
cmdEnter for the Button.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("yesID").InnerText = txtID.text
```

Comment: There was an error appear . This is my code : Private Sub cmdCheck_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdCheck.Click

        WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.yes.my/myselfcare/doLogin.do")
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("yesID").InnerText = txtID.Text
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").InnerText = txtPwd.Text
        WebBrowser1.Document.All("Submit").RaiseEvent("onclick")
    End Sub

Comment: What is the message and in which line?

Comment: WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("yesID").InnerText = txtID.Text NullReferenceException was unhandled . Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: There is no "Submit" button. This is image in link (<a>...</a>). You can't raise event, because element "Submit" not exist. I have no idea how to click link without html ID.

Comment: I ignore about click event . I tried with WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("yesID").InnerText = txtID.Text but the text in my textbox not copy it to the webbrowser

Comment: Hmm. Code tested on VB2010 and works with no errors. Maybe write code that wait until page loaded?

Comment: Thanks you for feedback . Resolved . I need to wait until the page is load completely .. But what about the click button?

Comment: That is the question... How to click an item that does not have html ID...? `RaiseEvent` and `InvokeMember` will not work.